# How to Create the Custom create function in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I want to change Create function
for avoiding the Global variable usage.
I want to pass my values (e.g scores) while Calling
and creating other scenes. One method i found is
the use of Global variable in create Function
but i want to use those values without using global
variables. Please reply me fast , i'm new in cocos2d-x.
and also tell me if there is any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i personally use these two approaches ... so choose which fits you the most!

take for example this ScoreScene class and how its created.

1)- approach one

```
class ScoreScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:

    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene(bool won, int score) {
        auto scene = Scene::create();
        auto layer = ScoreScene::create(won, score);
        scene->addChild(layer);
        return scene;
    }

    static ScoreScene* create(bool won, int score) {
        ScoreScene *layer = new(std::nothrow) ScoreScene;
        if (layer)
        {
            layer->isWinner = won;
            layer->m_score = score;
            if (layer->init())
            {
                layer->autorelease();
                return layer;
            }
        }
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(layer);
        return nullptr;
    }

    bool init() override {
        if(!layer->init()) return;
        // initialization code here
        return true;
    }

private:

    // your properties
    int m_score;
    bool isWinner;
};
```

1)- approach two (personally preferred)

make just one method which is createScene instead of two.

```
class ScoreScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:

    cocos2d::Scene* ScoreScene::createScene(bool won, int score)
    {
        ScoreScene *layer = new(std::nothrow) ScoreScene;
        if (layer)
        {
            layer->isWinner = won;
            layer->m_score = score;
            if (layer->init())
            {
                auto scene = Scene::create();
                layer->autorelease();
                scene->addChild(layer);
                return scene;
            }
        }
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(layer);
        return nullptr;
    }


    bool init() override {
        if(!layer->init()) return;
        // initialization code here
        return true;
    }

private:

    // your properties
    int m_score;
    bool isWinner;
};
```

Comment: that's my Answer. Thanks Joseph. I found the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same Approach But thanks for answering..

```
cocos2d::Scene* GameOverScene::createScene(unsigned int tempscoree)
{
    GameOverScene *pRet = new(std::nothrow) GameOverScene();
    if (pRet && pRet->init(tempscoree))
    {
        auto scene = Scene::create();
        pRet->autorelease();
        scene->addChild(pRet);
        return scene;
    }
    else
    {
        delete pRet;
        pRet = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
}


bool GameOverScene::init(unsigned int tempScore)
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Now i can use tempScore any where in to this init() method. 

}
```